# Shared memory in OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencl

I intend to perform vector manipulations and was trying a small dummy program with vector addition and multiplication. However, the code does not run due to limitations on my knowledge on shared memory. All the sources in the internet show 2D matrix operations which I cannot translate to my vector problems. Please try to explain where am I going wrong considering the fact I am a novice in OpenCL. The code is given below:

Host Code:

```
std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
cl::Context context;
cl::CommandQueue queue;
cl::Program program;
cl::Kernel kernel;

cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

deviceUsed = 0;

cl_context_properties properties[] =
{ CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0])(),0 };

context = cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, properties);
devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, devices[deviceUsed]);
cl::Program::Sources source( 1, std::make_pair(kernel_source.c_str(),  kernel_source.size()));
program = cl::Program(context, source);
program.build(devices);

std::vector < float > a;
std::vector < float > b;
std::vector < float > sum;
std::vector < float > prod;

int globalSize = 128;
int localSize = 16;

a.resize(globalSize);
b.resize(globalSize);
sum.resize(globalSize);
prod.resize(globalSize);

for (int i = 0; i < globalSize ; i++)
{
    a[i] = 1.0f * i;
    b[i] = 5.0f * i;
}
cl::Buffer buffer_A;
cl::Buffer buffer_B;
cl::Buffer buffer_sum;
cl::Buffer buffer_prod;

buffer_A = cl::Buffer (context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * globalSize);
buffer_B = cl::Buffer (context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * globalSize);

queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * globalSize , &a[0]);
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * globalSize , &b[0]);

buffer_sum = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * globalSize);
buffer_prod = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * globalSize);

kernel.setArg(0, buffer_A);
kernel.setArg(1, buffer_B);
kernel.setArg(2, buffer_sum);
kernel.setArg(3, buffer_prod);

queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(globalSize/localSize), cl::NDRange(N), NULL);
queue.finish();
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_sum, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * globalSize, &sum[0]);
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_prod, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * globalSize, &prod[0]);
```

Kernel:

```
#define STRINGI(ker) #ker
std::string kernel_source = STRINGI(

__kernel void KernelAddMul(__global float* a, __global float* b, __global float* sum, __global float* prod)
{
    unsigned int j = get_local_id(0);
    int N = get_local_size(0);
    unsigned int i = N * get_global_id(0) + j;

    float locSum[N];
    float locProd[N];

    __local float Asub[N];
    __local float Bsub[N];

    for(int k = 0; k < N; k++){

        Asub[k] = a[i];
        Bsub[k] = b[i];
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        locSum[k] = Asub[k] + Bsub[k];
        locProd[k] = Asub[k] * Bsub[k];
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        sum[i] = locSum[k];
        prod[i] = locProd[k];
     }

} 

);
```

Comment: Shared memory is a faster memory that is only seen within one work group. Between the kernels the data is accessed through global memory using cl buffers, so the shared memory can only be "allocated" and used within a kernel. For 1D you would probably use shared memory for reduction, saving intermediate values to avoid rewriting to global memory. To access it use `__local__`.

Comment: What do you mean your code does not run? Does it run and give wrong results or does it fail? You should check each OpenCL call to see if they return CL_SUCCESS. It would be beneficial for us if you could provide more information.

Comment: @parallelhighway I am using the Intel SDK and the code compiles. But when I print the values of sum and prod returned by the kernel it shows all 0s. I guess I am missing something trivial. There might be something wrong with the arguments of the enqueueNDRangeKernel statement in the host code or the kernel code where the local and global memory communicates. Please have a look at the code once. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your code does not run because your kernel does not compile.

The following lines are invalid:

```
int N = get_local_size(0);

float locSum[N];
float locProd[N];

__local float Asub[N];
__local float Bsub[N];
```

`N` must be a constant, you cannot dynamically size the arrays using `get_local_size(0)`.

I strongly recommend that you use a standalone compiler to compile your kernels: 
[CodeXL](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/CodeXL) is very good, as is the [Intel 
SDK for OpenCL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl). 
Anything is better than trying to debug your kernel in an application!

Comment: I am using the Intel SDK and the code compiles. But when I print the values of sum and prod returned by the kernel it shows all 0s. Even if I hard code the value N=16, the result is the same. I guess I am missing something trivial. There might be something wrong with the arguments of the enqueueNDRangeKernel statement in the host code or the kernel code where the local and global memory communicates. Please have a look at the code once. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ejaz I've run your kernel through both CodeXL and the Intel SDK and they both fail to compile, Intel gave the error "variable length arrays are not supported in OpenCL" even with N=16,. Your host code looks OK to me, but I use `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` so I'm not familiar with the API your using...

Comment: Oh. I am not being able to figure out what is going wrong in this code which just adds two vectors. Can you spot what mistake I am making or provide an alternate working solution?

Comment: It's not possible for me to debug your software on a different system. I recommend that you get something working using a simpler interface like [boost compute](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/compute/doc/html/index.html) or [sycl](https://www.khronos.org/sycl) first.